# Use package installed via composer in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-chosen

I have installed library called chosen js via composer. Now I have it in my composer.json file

```
"require": {
        "harvesthq/chosen": "^1.8"

    },
```

How can i use it in my project? Where do I need to require it ?

Comment: Do you run composer update in terminal?

Comment: If you've installed it via composer you should be able to access it anywhere using autoloader `use harvesthq\chosen;`, the case is probably wrong in my example but should point you in right drection

Answer (score 0):

Install any packages in the Laravel

(1)first way: via composer

open project path in terminal and fire this command

```
composer require harvesthq/chosen
```

(2)Second way: add package name in composer.json file

```
"require": {
        "harvesthq/chosen": "^1.8"

    },
```

and fire this command

```
composer update
```

Comment: i know i have my files on C:\wamp\www\logart\vendor\harvesthq but how can i use it? To require them. I need to use this lib